# Timestamp difference in Snowflake

Tags: sql, date, time-series, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, date-range

I want to find the time difference between two timestamps for each `id`.
When calculating it, only from **9am **till** 17pm** and **weekdays** are needed to be accounted.

[image]

e.g. for the first record, it must be calculated from *9am* on *2021-05-19*, hence the result would be 45 minutes.
For the second record, it would be 330 minutes, calculated as below:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF('minute', '2021-05-19 15:30:00'::timestamp, '2021-05-19 17:00:00'::timestamp) + 
TIMESTAMPDIFF('minute', '2021-05-20 09:00:00'::timestamp, '2021-05-20 13:00:00'::timestamp)
```

**Here is example data:**

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT 'A' AS id, '2021-05-18 18:30:00'::timestamp AS started_at, '2021-05-19 09:45:00'::timestamp AS ended_at UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' AS id, '2021-05-19 15:30:00'::timestamp AS started_at, '2021-05-20 13:00:00'::timestamp AS ended_at
    )
SELECT *
FROM t1
```

Comment: How do you want to handle partial hours? If your created was 16:15 and your completed was 09:45 the next day, what should be the result and why? You probably need to write a function that will loop through all the hours between your start and end dates and applies logic whether to include that hour in your total count

Comment: @NickW I just used hour in TIMESTAMPDIFF for simplicity. For partial hours, I would use minute instead. I used tstzrange to create business hours range in Postgres. Is there a similar function in Snowflake? 
That solution worked from here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67194137/time-difference-within-business-hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following UDF

```
create or replace function tsrange_intersection(s string, e string)
  RETURNS double
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
let minutes = 0
start = new Date(S)
end = new Date(E)
let t = start
while(t < end) {
    if ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].includes(t.getDay())
      && [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16].includes(t.getHours())) {
        minutes += 1
    }
    t = new Date(t.getTime() + 60*1000);
}
return minutes
$$;
```

This works as follows:

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT 'A' AS id, '2021-05-18 18:30:00' AS started_at, '2021-05-19 09:45:00' AS ended_at UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' AS id, '2021-05-19 15:30:00' AS started_at, '2021-05-20 13:00:00' AS ended_at
    )
SELECT tsrange_intersection(started_at, ended_at) minutes
FROM t1;

MINUTES
45
330
```